# Loop through rows in datagrid and get variables C#

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview, outlook

Ok so I have a datagrid which has a button to export data into an email, it currently with the code below, creates a new mail and it inserts the first row displayed in the datagrid correctly but doesn't insert any other rows.
I assume I need a loop IE my foreach statement (albeit empty) needs something in there but I cant figure it out, been stuck for hours) basically I just want to to loop through all the rows displayed from the stated 2 columns and then get them into the variable and then use that to insert into the subject body of the new mail item...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (MailItem)app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
{


}

var column1 = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"].Value;
var column2 = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value;

mailItem.Body = column1.ToString() + " - " + column2.ToString();
mailItem.Subject = this.subjectText.Text;
mailItem.To = this.senderText.Text;

//mailItem.Attachment.Add(logPath);//logPath is a string holding path to the log.txt file
//mailItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
mailItem.Display(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want to display every row, you need to replace `dataGridView2.SelectedRows` by `dataGridView2.Rows`, then, simply get the value of column1 and column2 at each iteration :

```
object column1 = "";
object column2 = "";
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if(!item.IsNewRow)
    {
        column1 = item.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value;
        column2 = item.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"].Value;
        mailItem.Body += column2 != null ? column2.ToString() : "" + " - " +
                         column1 != null ? column1.ToString() : "" + "\n";
}
```

Comment: getting Null Reference Exception error, guessing this is something to do with my datagrid references?

Comment: Check in debug to see what is null exactly please

Comment: @user3086447 Before concatenating the string put the condition is `row.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"].Value` and  `row.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"].Value` is not null.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I am not sure what he is asking me to code in, (I am quite new to this btw so the concepts I understand but the "and" and "is not null" I have no idea how to implement.

Comment: Please look at the updated code. The error came from the fact that the `foreach` loop iterates through the last empty row.

Comment: Now it is saying item doesnt exsist in context, sorry about this - I am noob.

Comment: I updated the code again so it can handle null values in your grid. Also, as @danish suggested, consider using column indexes instead of names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
        {
            builder.AppendLine(
                ((rows.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"].Value == null) ? "" : rows.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"].Value.ToString()) +
                " - " +
            ((rows.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value == null) ? "" : rows.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value.ToString()));


        }

        mailItem.Body = builder.ToString();
```

Also, try using column index if possible.